# Do gradient approximations with the normal derivate (which is an approximation of two infinitesimally close points) fail to describe nature sometimes?

Tags: calculus, limits, vector-analysis

Problem set up:
As I was repeating calculus one it got me thinking about the way we calculate gradients. We appoximate the slope of the tangent using a limit of two distinct points, where the distance between these two points gets infinitesimally small.

But let's say we have a function which is defined like this:

f(x) = $\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    x^2 \quad \textrm{if } x \neq 0.1 \\
    100 \quad \textrm{if } x = 0.1
  \end{array}
\right.$

If we now choose two infinitesimally near points around the peak of the function at 0.1 either we land on a slope which should be extremly high (or low), because of the linear function reaching for this peak or we end up with just the gradient of $x^2.$.

1. Does this function fall in a special category?
2. How do we apprimate a gradient at such a point?
3. Do such functions exist in nature (physics or anywhere else)?
4. Does it makes sense to ask for properties of the function at those points is it plain stupid, because there would be no sensible reason for asking those questions in "real life"?

(First post ever here, I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to ask^^)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In "real life" , "pathological" functions do not apply. We anyway can only model reality.

Comment: (1) Discontinuous function. Read **Spivak's "Calculus"** for a proper introduction to real analysis including the notion of continuity. (2) No such thing, and no such word as "apprimate". (3) No. Even the usual real numbers are mathematical objects, not necessarily with real-world representatives. (4) See first point.

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 0.1$ and therefore the derivative does not exist. However, we can easily construct a continuous function $g(x)$ that comes very close to your function, in the sense that overall (i.e. for most values of $x$) it looks like $x^2$ and is strongly peaked around $x = 0.1$. Here is such a function:

$$g(x) = x^2 + 99.99 * exp({-(x-0.1)^2}/{2\sigma ^2})$$

Here $\sigma$ is a small parameter. The smaller it is chosen, the more $g$ resembles $f$. Since $g$ is a continuous function, the derivative exists. It can easily be evaluated. It has a sharp positive peak around $0.1 - \sigma$ and a sharp negative peak around $0.1 + \sigma$. So this may be considerated the approximation you were seeking.

Sharply peaked functions do appear in physics. For example, a metal conductor in an external electric field will induce a surface charge density on the conductor with a typical thickness of $0.1$ nanometer. It is often convenient to ignore the thickness of the layer since it does not affect the physics. So for practical purposes the thickness can be considered zero, whereas the net surface charge remains finite.

Other examples are modelling a galaxy as a set of point masses (instead of stars), or modelling a gas in terms of point masses (instead of gas molecules). These numerical models typically use the Dirac delta function in their theoretical description.